# Как сверстать данный блок?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, frontend

помогите пожалуйста с данным блоком.
Вот не могу понять, Номер и текст вместе с временем отдельно тег писать или нужно прописать некий код помимо letter-spacing?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Благодарю заранее :)

Comment: Я бы сделал 3 блока - телефон(с иконкой вместе), текст, время

Comment: Тоже так считаю

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<nav class="nav">
    <a class="nav-link" href="tel:88121234567">8&nbsp;(812)&nbsp;123-45-67</a>
    <div class="text">Работаем 7 дней в неделю</div>
    <div class="daily-time">9:00&nbsp;-&nbsp;18:00</div>
</nav>
```

```
body {
    line-height: 30px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}

nav {
    display: flex;

    font-size: 18px;
}

.nav-link {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 50px;
}

a:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-right: 20px;

    vertical-align: middle;

    background: url("tel.png") no-repeat;
}

a:after {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1px;
    height: 18px;
    margin-left: 25px;

    pointer-events: none;

    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    
    
    background-color: #000;
}

.text {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 50px;
}

.text:after {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1px;
    height: 18px;
    margin-left: 25px;

    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    
    
    background-color: #000;
}
```

Comment: еще для полного фарша можно сделать последний блок тегом <time>

Comment: Не согласен, что нужно использовать тег time. Там же промежуток времени, а не точное время. (как в статьях)

Answer (score 0):

решил

```
<body>
  <div class="nav">
    <a href="tel:88121234567">8(812)123-45-67</a> |
    <span>Работаем 7 дней в неделю</span> |
    <span>9:00 - 18:00</span>
  </div>
</body>

.nav {
  text-align: center;
a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 15px 0 0;
}
span {
  margin: 0 10px;
  &:last-child {
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
  }
}
```